# Microsoft Advertising SDK doesn't deliverer ads

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

So I have a Windows Phone solution that has an ad in it.

When my Solution References

```
Microsoft.Advertising.SDK
Advertising.Mobile
Advertising.Mobile.UI
```

Everything works fine and I get ads. Unfortunately this has multiple references to the same DLL so I can't submit it to Microsoft this way. I am forced to either remove `Microsoft.Advertising.SDK` or the two `Advertising.Mobile` references.

When I change this at all however it refuses to serve ads. I am kind of at a loss now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only use **MicrosoftAdvertising.Mobile** and **Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI** and I am served ads. The SDK should only add the DLLs not reference itself.

Note:
You need to explicitly set width and height
Make sure the phone dialer, and web browser capabilities are enabled

Followup note:
Make sure that after you've removed the SDK DLL, that the xmlns references are not still pointing to it. The best route to take here is

1. Remove the XAML for the ad
2. Remove the xmlns declaration (usually at the top of the page, but sometimes will be declared in the ad itself)
3. Remove the bad DLL (the one ending in .SDK )
4. Do a Clean and then Build (clean out anything remaining from the DLL)
5. Add the xmlns reference (actual reference is below)
6. Add the ad to the page (example below)

Here is the xmlns reference:

```
xmlns:AdNamepace="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
```

Then the ad itself:

```
<AdNamespace:AdControl x:Name="myAd" Height="80" Width="480" 
                  AdUnitId="yourAdUnitIdHere" ApplicationId="yourIdHere"/>
```